# Why are these extra grid lines appearing?

Tags: modeling, snapping, orthographic

how would i reset the grid so there aren't all these other lines. Sometimes this causes remove doubles to not work and grid snapping sometimes isn't precise. For example i'll add a plane after snapping the 3d cursor to center of course, then scale and or duplicate and move it around snapping it to the grid. Eventually the extra lines pop up without me accidentally pressing anything. Why is this and how do i fix it? Thanks in advance :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which Blender version? This doesn't look like expected behavior.. possibly one of the wrinkles not yet ironed out of 2.8?

Comment: Im still using 2.79 I have yet to try 2.8 but this issue is inconsistent so when I do start using 2.8 it may take a while before i notice it. Ive only noticed it after modeling for a few hours at least.

Comment: OK, if it's happening in a stable version, perhaps that suggests something to do with the environment Blender is running in, not Blender itself? I'm no expert in this area.. Graphics Drivers? Let's hope someone who knows a bit more turns up to answer this one.

Comment: I opened the blend in 2.8 and the problem persists although it looks a bit different but thats probably just cause they changed the way the grid looks and whatnot

Comment: Looks a lot like a driver-related problem. Please post your hardware specs.

Comment: can you upload a .blend file that exhibits the issue? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: 1080ti ftw3 i7 6700k 16gb 3000mhz ram and always update my drivers with nvidia experience

Comment: Also they go away if i open a new blend and append everything to it, but im sure they will come back and the root problem is still there

Comment: @RileyChristian your screenshot is from 2.8 tough^^ anyway, this is really weird, and its only appearing after some time? I'd also suspect a driver issue. I also remember something similar happening in some 2.7 Build - at least on my pc. You can try other versions if it's also happening, maybe even different graphic driver.

Comment: The screenshots are from 2.79 and 2.8. The blend is from the 2.79. I always keep my drivers up to date with nvidia experience. Im starting a new project and just appending everything to it because the problem does goes away but unfortunately its made everything slightly off grid and ill have to manually recreate most things. Hopefully the issue wont come back but only time will tell.

Comment: After 2 weeks of working on a new project the weird extra lines start showing up again. Very confusing...